# "fatal: unable to find remote helper for 'https'" error when git clone

Tags: git

*Git 2.32.0* was installed from source on Termux proot-distro debian (bookworm)

I enter proot with this command: `proot-distro --isolated --user nonroot debian`

Git installation:

```
make configure
./configure
make
make install prefix=git DESTDIR=~/installations/installed/
```

I install in such a folder because I don’t want to clog up the system

Before that I installed the dependencies:

```
sudo apt install dh-autoreconf libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext libz-dev libssl-dev install-info
Note, selecting 'zlib1g-dev' instead of 'libz-dev'
```

When I run `git clone` the following error occurs:

```
warning: templates not found in git/git/share/git-core/templates
fatal: unable to find remote helper for 'https'
```

Note: *git* installed from apt does not produce errors and works properly

None of similar questions helped me with their answers...
Maybe someone can give diagnostic information instead of solutions, because if I have to recompile, I will have to wait a very long time... But the solution may not help

Failure of some popular answers:

- curl-devel is not installed (or libcurl4-gnutls-dev in Debian)

Verifying installation via apt:

```
apt list --installed | grep libcurl
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
libcurl3-gnutls/stable-security,now 7.88.1-10+deb12u4 arm64 [installed,automatic]
libcurl4-gnutls-dev/stable-security,now 7.88.1-10+deb12u4 arm64 [installed]
libcurl4/stable-security,now 7.88.1-10+deb12u4 arm64 [installed,automatic]
```

Checking the occurrence of the following error message

```
configure:22159: result: no
configure:22184: WARNING: libcurl development lib not found. On Debian this is found in libcurl4-gnutls-dev. On RHEL5/Fedora11 it's in curl-devel. On RHEL6/Fedora12 it's in libcurl-devel.
configure:22703: checking for libsqlite3
configure:22738: gcc -std=gnu99 -o conftest -I/usr/include/curl -I/home/praveen/LIs/nosql/membase-server_src/install/include -L/home/praveen/LIs/nosql/membase -server_src/install/lib conftest.c -lsqlite3 >&5
conftest.c:50:27: fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
```

in `config.log`:

```
cat config.log | grep "libcurl development lib not found"
```

(nothing)

- git exec path that does not exist

`git --exec-path`:

```
git/git/libexec/git-core
```

The folder `installations/installed/git/git/libexec/git-core` and it's content exists. (`installations/installed/git/bin` in *PATH*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helped me was not using DESTDIR during installation

You can first specify the path from DESTDIR in the prefix, and then glue it with the prefix and everything will be as you want